# SKSpriteNode multiple textures

Tags: objective-c, ios7, sprite-kit, skspritenode, sktexture

What is the best way to have a `SKSpriteNode` **composed of multiple images** ?

I found that `[SKTexture textureWithImage:image];` doesn't use the scale property (when I use it with a custom bitmap assembled image I have a small `SKSpriteNode`).

Maybe I can create a link between multiples `SKSpriteNode` but I'm not sure it is a good idea for collisions detection.

**EDIT:**

*Solution that works for me.*
This code takes 3 textures, draw them in the `GraphicsContext` that creates a `UIImage`.
Then I add this `UIImage` to my `SKNode` which now have multiple textures. However, it is **very important** to specify the `SKNode` **size property** `[self setSize:CGSizeMake(WIDTH_HERO, HEIGHT_HERO)];` in my case. If you dont, the node will use a **bad scale factor** and you'll have small textures (non retina).

```
CGSize mergedSize = CGSizeMake(WIDTH_HERO, HEIGHT_HERO);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(mergedSize, NO, 0.0f);

[textureImage1 drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, WIDTH_HERO, textureImage1.size.height)];
[textureImage2 drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 40, WIDTH_HERO, textureImage2.size.height)];
[textureImage3 drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, WIDTH_HERO, textureImage3.size.height)];

UIImage *mergedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

[self setTexture:[SKTexture textureWithImage:mergedImage]];
```

Comment: you need multiple sprites, put them in the same sknode and use accumulatedFrame for collisions

Comment: Do you really have to use SKTexture to create a sprite node?

Comment: I guess yes. Even if you can create an SKSpriteNode without explicitly specifying the texture, there is one behind it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create another `SKSpriteNode` with the next texture and call `addChild:` on the original node, then change the position of the new node relative to the parent node.

This is inside my subclass of `SKSpriteNode`;

```
    UIImage* bottom = [[UIImage imageNamed: @"obstacle_base"] resizableImageWithCapInsets: UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
    UIImage* top = [UIImage imageNamed: @"obstacle_top"];

    SKTexture* bottomT = [SKTexture textureWithImage: bottom];
    SKTexture* topT = [SKTexture textureWithImage: top];

    [self setTexture: bottomT];

    // create top
    SKSpriteNode* topNode = [[SKSpriteNode alloc] initWithTexture: topT];
    topNode.position = CGPointMake(0, height/2 - topNode.size.height/2);
    [self addChild: topNode];
```